# server 2012 not receiving data on specific port

Tags: port, block

I installed a windows server 2012 r2 standard + sql 2008 r2 standard on a new dell server for a client of mine as regular workgroup file server (not acting as a Domain Controller) 3 months ago and all was working well. I've installed symantec endopint 12.5 on it and am using a tp-link TL-ER604W vpn router as the main router on it's local network.
The client bought a medical machine that sample heart rate and blood pressure (Goldway G60), Which supposed to send a small text data through a port to the server and a listening software installed on the server is supposed to integrate the data on a patient's file.
In order to test that data is delivered from the G60, I've installed a program called Timon 1.3.01 which monitor a specific ip/port for the data that is sent to a specific computer it's installed on. (I install it on a computer with ip 192.168.1.110, Set the G60 to send data to 192.168.1.110 on port 6768 and then set the timon to listen to that port on that computer and see the data).
I am not able to get the server to acknowledge any data sent from the G60 machine on port 6768 using the Timon software, But I DO get acknowledge of the data if I connect the device to another computer on the network (Even if i give it the server's IP).
I also can ping to the machine and ping is fine from the server too, But for some reason I can't get the data from the G60 to the server.
This is what I tried :
1. Disabling firewall on server
2. Disabling firewall SERVICE on server
3. Removing SEP 12.5 completely from server
4. Running the server in safe mode with network and disabling firewall service
5. Opening port on firewall (Inbound and outbound)
6. Opening DMZ on router for server address
7. Trying it with another router
8. Connecting only router and G60 to another router
9. Tried different Ip and port settings on the G60

When runing netstat -an it seems that 6768 port is being listened :
  TCP    0.0.0.0:6768           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
I also used sysinternals psping 192.168.1.110:6768 and I get pings back from the server on that port.
The G60 local tech support said that the Timon software is working on THEIR server 2012, So it supposed to be compatible with 2012 server.

I would really appreciate some insights on how to make the G60 communicate with the 2012 server.

Thank you

Comment: I'm confused. Is this question about resolving a problem with the test software on the test server or is it about resolving a problem with the real software on the real server?

Comment: The software Timon, is that the program that writes data to the patients file, or is that a separate bit of software to test to see if te G60 is sending data?

Comment: Hi Joe and drifter. @ Drifter - The Timon is a software that show if some data gets from the G60 to a specific ip and port. @Joe - I'm trying to resolve the problem with the real server not getting data from the G60 while a workstation does get data. Thanks you for looking into my problem

Comment: Update : Managed to get some data on server's port from the G60, But it's not consistant. I used HL7 reader to get data on ports 6770 and 6771 it worked great for about half an hour, Then tried closing the hl7 reader and opening it again - Data stopped arriving.....Changed ip momentarily on the g60 and returned the old ip - data continue to be received on server....the inconsistancy on the G60 data sending is driving me nuts.....

Comment: Hello again.

Just wanted to update - 

Connected a windows 7 x64 laptop with open ports and a simple switch to the G60 monitor and saw it stops sending data after few minutes. Changing his ip manually and then changing it back - Made it send data again. The the fault was with the G60 monitors (It happened with two exact G60 monitors).

Thank you for your help !